# how to add file attachment(like pdf,doc,xml) in a contact form

Tags: php

i have a contact form with out file attachment(its working properly) .How i can convert this contact form into file attachment.Can you also tell me how this file attachment script works.I tried web but there is no clear answer for this problem.this is my script

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br/>

 <label for="email">Email address:</label><br/>
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br/>

 <label for="topic">Subject:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="topic" name="topic" /><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
<label>Upload a Menu:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" size="20"><br>


<label for="comments">Your comments:</label><br/>
<textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br/>

<button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

// Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = "Contact: $topic";
$message = "$name said: $comments";
$headers = "From: $email";

// Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Redirect
echo('<br> your mail has been send<br>');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file is saved to a temporary location. You can then copy the file from there to wherever you want to use or permanently save it. All of the file information is actually in the `$_FILES` superglobal instead of `$_POST`.

In your case, the path where the file is temporarily saved can be found in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.

See [the manual here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), where it explains how this works with examples.

Attaching the file to an email, however, is another beast. You'd be best served to use a PHP mailer class for this rather than just using `mail()` yourself. Look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), for example.